Connecting Bézier curves smoothly
What is the "trick" to connect two Bézier curves smoothly? Such as the connection point in the below example?
\documentclass[border=2pc,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[lightgray] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\draw [very thick, ] (1,1) .. controls (2,7) and (3.5,7) .. (5,3) .. controls (6,1.5) and (7,1.5) .. (8,8);
\draw[red] (5,3) circle [radius=.5];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



(3.5,7)-(5.3) and (6,1.5)-(5,3) are not proportional, so the curves do not connect smoothly.

What @SergeiGolovan wrote. Here is a picture (done in MetaPost) where one can see it clearly.

To elaborate a bit, how would you like your picture to change?  How much are you allowing to adjust the cubic portions to make things line up?  Or are you just looking for a generic "cubic polynomial" shape?

@mickep So is it the case that the gradients of the control handles do not align?

Yes indeed, so if you specify curves like that, either you have to make sure they align, or you will get corners. I don't know tikz, so I don't know about other ways to get more or less what you look for, but in metapost it could be something like (1,1){dir 80} .. {dir -70}(5,3) .. {dir 80}(8,8). Maybe something similar work in tikz.

You could try using the hobby TikZ library. That lets you define curves by specifying points that they should pass through, with an option for directions at some of those points.

It depends on what you mean by "smoothly" and how you are willing to alter your curve. Instead of using control points, you can use to where you can give the angles like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (1,1) .. controls (2,7) and (3.5,7) .. (5,3) .. controls (6,1.5) and (7,1.5) .. (8,8);
\draw[red, ultra thick] (1,1) to[out=80, in=110, looseness=2.9] (5,3) to[out=180+110, in=-100, looseness=1.3] (8,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit:
Here is an other way to specify the angles but with control points:
\draw[green, ultra thick] (1,1) .. controls +(80:9) and +(110:1) .. (5,3) .. controls +(110:-3.5) and +(-100:1) .. (8,8);


Somehow, making curves using to confuses me even more.

That is not a very constructive comment. What confuses you?

@blackened When using to, the in-degree of one point corresponds to the out-degree of the next point; the two values must differ by 180 degrees, so that the tangential vectors point into opposite directions. In the example by hpekristiansen, you have [... in=110 ...] (5,3) [... out=110+180 ...].
