how can draw curve with a loop?
I am trying to draw a curve with a loop as shown in the image. After a lot of hard work, I managed to draw it, but it does not appear as smooth as in the image. Can anyone help me with this? I would be very grateful.
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, ext.topaths.arcthrough, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
% Define the custom dark red color
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{180, 0, 0}
% Define the custom dark blue color
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0, 0, 139}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % Grid (optional, for visualization)
    \draw[step=1,gray,thin,dotted] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
    % Draw the self-intersecting curve
    \draw[thick, blue, smooth](-2, 1.5) .. controls (-0.5, -0.5) and (2,0.5) .. (1.5, 1.5);
    \draw[thick, blue, smooth](1.5, 1.5) .. controls (0, 2.2) and (-0.7,-0.7) .. (1.5, -2);
        \draw(-2.02,-2.02)--(-2.02,2.02);
    \draw(-2.02,-1)--(-1.96,-1)node[left]{\scalebox{0.5}{$-0.5$}};
    \draw(-2.02,-2)--(-1.96,-2)node[left]{\scalebox{0.5}{$-1$}};
    \draw(-2.02,0)--(-1.96,0)node[left]{\scalebox{0.5}{$0$}};
    \draw(-2.02,1)--(-1.96,1)node[left]{\scalebox{0.5}{$0.5$}};
    \draw(-2.02,2)--(-1.96,2)node[left]{\scalebox{0.5}{$1$}};
    
    \draw(2.02,-2.02)--(2.02,2.02);
    \draw(2.02,1)--(1.96,1);
    \draw(2.02,2)--(1.96,2);
    \draw(2.02,0)--(1.96,0);
    \draw(2.02,-1.0)--(1.96,-1.0);
    \draw(2.02,-2)--(1.96,-2);

    \draw(-2.02,-2.02)--(2.02,-2.02);
    \draw(-1,-2.02)--(-1,-1.96)node[below]{\scalebox{0.5}{$-0.5$}};
    \draw(-2,-2.02)--(-2,-1.96)node[below]{\scalebox{0.5}{$-1$}};
    \draw(0.0,-2.02)--(0.0,-1.96)node[below]{\scalebox{0.5}{$0$}};
    \draw(1,-2.02)--(1,-1.96)node[below]{\scalebox{0.5}{$0.5$}};
    \draw(2,-2.02)--(2,-1.96)node[below]{\scalebox{0.5}{$1$}};
    
    \draw(-2.02,2.02)--(2.02,2.02);
    \draw(-1,2.02)--(-1,1.96);
    \draw(-2,2.02)--(-2,1.96);
    \draw(0.0,2.02)--(0.0,1.96);
    \draw(1,2.02)--(1,1.96);
    \draw(2,2.02)--(2,1.96);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Looks like a curve that can be drawn using a parametrization. Is it a famous trisectrix?

This looks like the Folium of Descartes... Let me see if I can find a parameterization.

you're loading pgfplots but appear to be constructing axes by hand. don't do that. and don't scale text if you can help it. if you have a description, use tikz visualization or pgfplots. if you really need to do it by hand, consider using hobby. (consider using hobby anyhow.)

@mickep  its called "Jordan-Kurve" in germen.

This question might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/731048/connecting-b%c3%a9zier-curves-smoothly

Also, as @cfr mentioned, hobby lets you use .. instead of -- as a path

@NBur yes I got it. Can you placed it as answer. so i will accept it as best answer. Thank you

There is also this Q&A (which does not make use of pgfplots, but maybe contains helpful insights): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224861/47927
